# NestJS failed with the error: "Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit"

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I'm encountering issues with running Jest test in my [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/) project. I've followed the setup guides and examples provided, but my test is failing to execute properly. Here's breakdown of my setup and the problem I'm facing:

#### Problem:

When running [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) test for *"updating user account"* unit test, the test fails to *throw an error if the user wants to change the email which is already in used*. I've ensured that all dependencies are correctly installed, and I've followed the recommended configuration for Jest testing with NestJS. The error occurred as below:

```bash
/src/users/users.service.ts:86
                throw new common_1.HttpException('The email is already taken', common_1.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                      ^

HttpException: The email is already taken
    at UsersService.update (/src/users/users.service.ts:86:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  response: 'The email is already taken',
  status: 400,
  options: undefined
}

Node.js v18.16.0
 FAIL  src/users/users.service.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit

      at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (../node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:181:21)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.608 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

#### Relevant Code:

Here's a part of my `UsersService`:

```
// users.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private readonly usersRepository: Repository<User>,
    @InjectRepository(Verification)
    private readonly verificationsRepository: Repository<Verification>,
    private readonly mailerService: MailerService,
  ) {}

  async update(id: number, updateUserInput: UpdateUserInput): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.usersRepository.findOneBy({ id });
    if (!user) {
      throw new HttpException('User not found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    if (updateUserInput.email) {
      // check if the email is already used
      const duplicatedEmailUser = await this.usersRepository.findOneBy({
        id: Not(id),
        email: updateUserInput.email,
      });
      if (duplicatedEmailUser) {
        throw new HttpException(
          'The email is already taken',
          HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        );
      }
      // set new values
      user.email = updateUserInput.email;
      user.isVerified = false;
      // create verification code
      const verification = await this.verificationsRepository.save(
        this.verificationsRepository.create({ user }),
      );
      // send verification code through email
      this.mailerService.sendMail({
        to: user.email,
        from: 'please-no-reply <"no-reply@gmail.com">',
        subject: '[NestJS Test] Verification code for your account',
        html: `<p>Your verification code: ${verification.code}</p>`,
      });
    }
    return await this.usersRepository.save(user);
  }
}
```

And here's my test code:

```
// users.service.spec.ts
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { Verification } from './entities/verification.entity';
import { MailerService } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { Not, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

type MockRepository<T> = Partial<Record<keyof Repository<T>, jest.Mock>>;

const mockRepository = () => ({
  create: jest.fn(),
  delete: jest.fn(),
  findOne: jest.fn(),
  findOneBy: jest.fn(),
  save: jest.fn(),
});

const mockMailerService = () => ({
  sendMail: jest.fn(),
});

// Start test
describe('UsersService', () => {
  let usersService: UsersService;
  let mailerService: MailerService;
  let usersRepository: MockRepository<User>;

  // https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown#repeating-setup
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UsersService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
          useValue: mockRepository(),
        },
        {
          provide: MailerService,
          useValue: mockMailerService(),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();
    usersService = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
    mailerService = module.get<MailerService>(MailerService);
    usersRepository = module.get(getRepositoryToken(User));
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(usersService).toBeDefined();
  });
  describe('update', () => {
    const id = 1;
    const oldUser = { email: 'olduser@gmail.com', isVerified: true };
    const newUser = { email: 'newuser@gmail.com', password: 'test1234' };
    it('should fail if the user using the email already exists', async () => {
      // due to `findOneBy` is used twice in usersService, so I mock resolved value twice separately.
      usersRepository.findOneBy
        .mockResolvedValueOnce(oldUser)
        .mockResolvedValueOnce(newUser);
      const result = usersService.update(id, newUser);
      expect(usersRepository.findOneBy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
      expect(usersRepository.findOneBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, { id });
      expect(usersRepository.findOneBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2, {
        id: Not(id),
        email: newUser.email,
      });
      await expect(result).rejects.toEqual(
        new HttpException('The email is already taken', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST),
      );
    });
  });
});
```

#### What I've Tried

- Add `--maxWorkers` option when running `jest --maxWorkers 1 --watch` to see the real error, but still get the same one.
- Append and remove `await` keyword where it is required.

#### Environment:

- NestJS version: 10.3.2
- Jest version: 29.5.12
- Node.js version: 18.16.0
- Operating System: macOS Sonoma 14.3.1 (Apple M1)

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!